# How to count children in a nested list

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, recursion

I have a nested list with children which can hold its own children. This can be 5 level or more deep.

I want to calculate the count of all children for each item in the nested list. I wrote a recursive function to do so, but its too slow. Is there some better way?

This is what i have so far.

```
   public NestedData{
      public string bookName {get; set;}
      public IList<NestedData> Children {get; set;}
   }
    public int GetChildCount(){
        return Children.Sum(x=>x.GetChildCount());
    }
```

Comment: How can this be too slow? Also, are you sure there is no infinite loop? Won't GetChildCount() always return 0?

Comment: What's the definition of `NestedData`?

Comment: I got a large dataset. List contains over 1million records and for each record there can be multiple child.. and their child can have more child. The count will not be 0 if the list is hydrated with that much data.

Comment: NestedData is just a simple class

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: public NestedData{


public string bookName {get; set;}

public IList<NestedData> Children {get; set;}

}

Comment: Could a parent data be the child data of one of its children? If so, you're going to get an infinite loop.

Comment: Hi, no its not. I am not getting infinite loop. I am able to count all the childrens accurately. However, the performance is very slow. I am looking for an alternative to this recursive function. Thanks

Comment: There are no edge conditions in your recursive routine, it should always return 0. Adding a lot of 0s should be 0. Could you provide code that produces non-zero result?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i got this sorted.

I am using a binary search to search and count each child node.